# Selection from dropdown list that loads a div into another div (IE8, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu, onclick, onsubmit

I'm just starting out to learn javascript and it seems like I have ran into a wall regarding drop down list and loading a div into another div upon selection. I'm setting up a drop down box that is nothing more then a list of different divs with embedded videos. When selected I want the div to be loaded into the main div

Now the code I have below works on Firefox, but not on Chrome or IE8. I've searched and read that IE8 and Chrome doesn't like having onclick within the option tag. If true, how do I go about making the code below useful on IE8 and Chrome?

What I've tried so far:

Using onsubmit and adding a submit button - couldn't get it to work

Using onchange - Couldn't get it to work!

At this point I wouldn't be surprised if I'm just misusing the event handlers and possibly my function not going far enough, but I've been stuck for hours trying different things to no avail.

Any Suggestions?

```
     <div id="videodiv" style='display: none'> Some embedded video code</div>

     <div id="videodiv2" style='display: none'> Different Embedded video code</div>

     <div id="videoPlayback"> The div where all the embedded videos will end up loading</div>     


      <script type="text/javascript">
      function playVideo(sourceId, targetId) {
      if (typeof(sourceId)=='string') {sourceId=document.getElementById(sourceId);}
      if (typeof(targetId)=='string') {targetId=document.getElementById(targetId);}
      targetId.innerHTML=sourceId.innerHTML;
      return false;
                   }
      </script>

<select><option selected>Please Select...
<option onclick='return playVideo("videodiv2","videoPlayback")'>Video Div2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with jquery:

```
<div id="videodiv" style='display: none'> Some embedded video code</div>

     <div id="videodiv2" style='display: none'> Different Embedded video code</div>

     <div id="videoPlayback"> The div where all the embedded videos will end up loading</div>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var sourceDiv;
      var targetDiv;
      function playVideo(sourceId, targetId) {
      sourceDiv=$("#"+sourceId);
      targetDiv=$("#"+targetId);
      targetDiv.html(sourceDiv.html());
       }
      </script>

<select id="videos"><option selected="selected" >Please Select...</option>
<option value="videodiv">Video Div1</option>
<option value="videodiv2">Video Div2</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

function videoChanged() {
    //var videoSelectList = $('select#videos');
    var selectedValue = $('#videos').val();

    //alert(selectedValue);

    if (selectedValue != 'Please Select...') {
        playVideo(selectedValue,'videoPlayback');
    }
}

$(function() {
    //alert('my alert');
    $('select#videos').change(videoChanged);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You! This helped a lot. Looking at both answers, I need to start looking into jquery to help me with issues like this. I guess its another thing to learn!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that works; it uses jQuery just for convenience, but you can use *standard javascript* (pass me the term) without problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/MisterJack/qw6DL/

The main issue was that the HTML was wrong, especially the `select` tag wasn't closed, as well as the `option` tag.

What I did is simply bind the `onChange` event of the **select** (not the option!) to a function that updates the content.

This function searches the `option` which is currently selected, reads its `value` attribute (which is the id of the div to load content from) and updates the content accordingly.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var domElement = $('select option:selected').attr('value');
    $('#videoPlayback').html($('#' +  domElement.toString()).html()); 
});
```